# Problems with SHA 2 Hashing and Java

Tags: security, hash, cryptography, sha

I am working on following the SHA-2 cryptographically functions as stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2.

I am examining the lines that say:

- begin with the original message of length L bits append a single '1' bit;
- append K '0' bits, where K is the minimum number >= 0 such that L + 1 + K + 64 is a multiple of 512
- append L as a 64-bit big-endian integer, making the total post-processed length a multiple of 512 bits.

I do not understand the last two lines. If my string is short can its length after adding K '0' bits be 512. How should I implement this in Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it should be made clear that the "string" that is talked about is not a Java `String` but a bit string. These algorithms are binary/bit based. The implementation will generally not handle bits but bytes. So there is a translation phase where you should see bytes instead of bits.

SHA-512 is operated on in blocks of 512 bits (SHA-224/256) or 1024 bits (SHA-384/512). So basically you have a 64 or 128 byte buffer that you are filling before operating on it. You could also directly cache the data in 32 bit `int` fields (SHA-224/256) or 64 bit `long` fields, as that is the word size that is operated on.

Now the padding is relatively simple procedure. The padding is called bit-padding. As it is used in big-endian mode (SHA-2 fortunately uses this instead of the braindead little endian mode in SHA-3) the padding consists of a single bit set on the highest order bit in a byte, with the rest filled by zero's. That makes for a value of `(byte) 0x80` which must be put in the buffer.

If you cannot create this padding because the buffer is full then you will have to process the previous block, and then set the first bit of the now available buffer to `(byte) 0x80`. In the newer Java you can also use `(byte) 0b1_0000000` byte the way, which is more explicit.

Now you simply add zero's until you have 8 to 16 bytes left, again depending on the hash output size used. If there aren't enough bytes then fill till the end, process the block, and re-start filling with zero bytes until you have 8 or 16 bytes left again.

Now finally you have to encode the number of *bits* in those 8 or 16 bytes you've left. So multiply your input by eight, and make sure you encode those bytes in the same way as you'd expect in Java with the least significant bits as much to the right as possible. You might want to use `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putLong-long-` for this if you don't want to program it yourself. You may probably forget about anything over 2^56 bytes anyway, so if you have SHA-384/SHA-512 then simply set the first eight bytes to zero.

And that's it, except that you still need to process that last block and then use as many bytes from the left as required for your particular output size.

Comment: Note that both Bouncy Castle and the Java source code are readily available. Sometimes they are not that easy to read so I've been nice and described it instead.